# Obtener de una cadena de texto solamente valores alfanuméricos, pero a su vez excluir números que estén sueltos

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy intentando obtener de una cadena de texto solamente valores alfanuméricos. ***Pero a su vez quiero excluir números que estén sueltos***. Es decir:

```
const miString = 'hola! 8932p ++ 1234 automovil v2 etc 399';
const resultado = miString.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\u00C0-\u00ff]+/g, ' ');

console.log(resultado); // hola 8932pe 1234 automovil v2 etc 399
```

Lo ideal, y no estoy dando con ello por más ejemplos que encuentre:

```
console.log(resultado); // hola 8932pe automivil v2 etc
```

PD: `u00C0-\u00ff` lo implemento para aceptar distintos formatos de codificación.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te pongo una solución en otra expresión regular...

```js
const miString = 'hola! 8932p ++ 1234 automovil v2 etc 399';
const resultado = miString.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\u00C0-\u00ff]+/g, ' ');
const resultado1 = resultado.replace(/\b\d+\b/g, '');

// hola 8932pe 1234 automovil v2 etc 399
console.log(resultado);

// hola 8932pe automivil v2 etc
console.log(resultado1);
```

El modificador **\b** permite buscar sólo "palabras" completas y el modificador **\d** indica dígitos.
Con lo cual al poner `\b\d+\b` estamos limitando a palabras completas que incluyan 1 o más dígitos.

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu respuesta y explicar lo que hace el regex que sugerís? (la explicación no es para mí, sino para otros que encuentren esta respuesta y no comprendan su funcionamiento).